# Extract the country zip code based on the full country code - DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have in my data information about place as full post code for example CZ25145. I would like to create new column for this with value CZ. How to do this?
I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({

'CODE_LOAD_PLACE' : ['PL43100', 'CZ25905', 'DE29333', 'DE29384', 'SK92832']
},)
```

I would like to get it like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

'CODE_LOAD_PLACE' : ['PL43100', 'CZ25905', 'DE29333', 'DE29384', 'SK92832'],
'COUNTRY_LOAD_PLACE' : ['PL', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DE', 'SK']
},)
```

I try use .factorize and .groupby but no positive final effect.

Comment: If it's not in the United States of America, it's not a ZIP code. The more general concept is postal code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str` and select the first 2 characters:

```
df["COUNTRY_LOAD_PLACE"] = df["CODE_LOAD_PLACE"].str[:2]
```